# Is there a way to put scrolling text in a profile on a site I don't own

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

On some sites, you can use limited HTML in your own user profile (or other user-controlled space).

I'm looking for a way to put scrolling text in a profile. If I owned the site I could accomplish this with css and/or javascript.

I attempted to adapt a css-only solution, to fit it into a style attribute. I am able to do some transforms, but I can't seem to get any kind of animation without access to the header. (I even tried a marquee HTML tag.)

Is there a workaround for this?

Clarification: scrolling right to left from off-screen to off-screen, then repeat. OR text bouncing back and forth within its bounds.

Comment: Unless you're able to add markup (which I sincerely hope you're not), then no, thankfully. I guess you might try an animated GIF though, you know, since it's 1999 again.

Comment: I did reference "limited HTML." The M is for markup.  
I've been trying to do it in <P>, <div>, <span> tags, but I'm open to suggestion.